# Selecting Canvas Text

Tags: javascript

I like  to place a cursor for canvas text and make as a selectable one. how it can be proceed? if any example or demo which u share means it will be very useful for me

Comment: As far as I know the canvas is for drawing things (including texts) but not for selecting and editing things.

Answer (score 0):

The `<canvas>` HTML5 element is purely for bitmap output, it is not selectable in any way.

According to the [W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-canvas-element):

> The canvas element provides scripts with a resolution-dependent bitmap
>   canvas, which can be used for rendering graphs, game graphics, or
>   other visual images on the fly.
>
> Authors should not use the canvas element in a document when a more
>   suitable element is available. For example, it is inappropriate to use
>   a canvas element to render a page heading...
>
> In non-interactive, static, visual media, if the canvas element has
>   been previously painted on (e.g. if the page was viewed in an
>   interactive visual medium and is now being printed, or if some script
>   that ran during the page layout process painted on the element), then
>   the canvas element represents embedded content with the current image
>   and size. Otherwise, the element represents its fallback content
>   instead.
>
> In non-visual media, and in visual media if scripting is disabled for
>   the canvas element or if support for canvas elements has been
>   disabled, the canvas element represents its fallback content instead.

Comment: Actually canvas text editor is there visit http://www.lutzroeder.com/html5/textor/

Comment: @Karthi Impressive - from a brief read of the JavaScript source code, it looks like they're calculating the text selection virtually from the cursor position. Then updating the canvas to make it appear the text has been selected. Seems like a lot of overhead!